# How to use orderInCategory

Tags: android, menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:title="@string/item_name_1"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:orderInCategory="3" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:title="Create"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/create"
        />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:title="Delete"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/delete"
        />

</menu>
```

I am trying to use orderIncategory attribute of item tag in menu but it is not wrking as no changes  are getting reflected. Am I doing anything wrong

Answer (score 0):

The order in which the menu items will appear within the menu. The menu items are arranged from left to right in ascending order of integer value of `orderInCategory` (i.e. 1,2,3... -> left to right).

The items with the lowest orderInCategory values are displayed as actions, and the remaining items are displayed in the overflow menu.